How to write to ATmega328P EEPROM without supporting libraries?
IMPORTANT NOTE: I do not want to use a library to achieve this. No "avr/io.h" and no "avr/eeprom.h". I want to learn how to implement libraries like these.
Problem: Let's say I wanted to write a single byte to the EEPROM of my UNO. From the data sheet I see the following
available EEPROM: 1Kbytes (1024 bytes)

This is the quoted description
The EEPROM address registers – EEARH and EEARL specify the EEPROM address in the 256/512/512/1K bytes EEPROM space. The EEPROM data bytes are addressed linearly between 0 and 255/511/511/1023. The initial value of EEAR is undefined. A proper value must be written before the EEPROM may be accessed. EEAR8 is an unused bit in ATmega328P and must always be written to zero.
My confusion began here. From the register description EEARH bits 1-7 are reserved and bit 0 must always be 0. This leaves us with only EEARL (an 8-bit register) to address all 1024 bytes. This is impossible as we have only [0, 256) unique values available to us. So I kept reading and found this contained in the data sheet.

This states that the EEPROM is split into pages where each page is 4 bytes. This made sense to me (1024/4) = 256. Perfect, I could individually address every page with EEARL.
This is where my confusion continued. Say I wanted to write the second byte in the EEPROM  with some value. However, we have just concluded that to cover the entire address space of the EEPROM we must only address pages. So how would I write the second byte?
I feel like I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on here? I'm going to continue on with some thoughts on how this might work and maybe that will help uncover said misunderstanding.
Idea 1: I could load the first pages address (0x00) into EEARL and execute a write. But this writes to the first byte in the page I assume? If I didn't care about the first byte then I could write a 2 byte word to the EEPROM. Clobbering the first byte but successfully writing the second. HOWEVER, the EEPROM Data Register (value to be written) is 8-bits. Therefore, I can only write a byte at a time so how could I write a 2 byte value.
Idea 2: I could load the first pages address (0x00) into EEARL and execute a write. If I proceeded to leave EEARL untouched and wrote a subsequent byte maybe the byte being written is automatically incremented and I have successfully written the second byte?
Thank you in advance for any help given!

You are using some outdated datasheet that gives incorrect information. In the current DS it is stated that ATMEGA328 contains EEAR9 and EEAR8. So you can address any EEPROM byte.

please check actual DS

Thank you Peter! Lesson learned….. use the most up to date information

@dev_jeb Actually Atmel in particular were infamous for their poor quality documentation. Things have gotten somewhat better after the Microchip merger, but you are using a very old MCU from the 1990s here, so it will be "Atmel quality" documentation.

That is very interesting. I appreciate the insights.
